# Cannot change database running in docker

Tags: docker, mariadb

I cannot change the database from outside of container.

Im running mariaDB in docker container that was created using api and this body.

```
{
"Image": "mariadb/server:10.4",
"env": ["MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass",
             "MYSQL_DATABASE=test",
             "MYSQL_USER=user1",
             "MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass"],
    "HostConfig": {
        "PortBindings": {
            "3306/tcp": [{"HostPort": "3309"}]
        }
    }
    
}
```

I can get into the db using:

```
sudo mysql -h 172.17.0.6 -u root -p
```

but all changes i do are not persistent (creating users, giving privileges, restore db from dump etc.).

Although i can make changes to DB from inside container eg:

```
docker exec -it nameOFContainer bash
```

I would like to know why my container behaves this way and is there any way how to change the behaviour?

Comment: is `docker inspect nameOFContainer` give you same IP as `172.17.0.6 `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things that you have to do:

1. You have already mapped the host port 3309 to port 3306 of the container. So while connecting to the DB, use this port form the host.

> For example:
>
> ```
> mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P3309 -p
> ```

2. For the database changes to persist, use **docker volumes**. Like this:

> ```
> -v $HOME/docker/volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
> ```
>
> The **$HOME/docker/volumes/mysql** directory in your host is mapped to **/var/lib/mysql** directory of your docker container (this is where your database gets necessary files from).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a volume to persist the MariaDB data. You can use option -v on docker run. I suppose this is possible in API also.

```
-v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb